# DynamoDB Cross Region Copy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The article [Cross Region Export and Import of DynamoDB Tables](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cross-region-import-and-export-of-dynamodb-tables/) makes the following remark:

> Let’s take a quick tour of the export and import features, both of
>   which can be accessed from the DynamoDB tab of the AWS Management
>   Console.

Where exactly are these options Jeff Barr is speaking of. I don't see any `export` or `import` options.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of points:

1. That artile is from 2014 - a lot has changed in the last 5 years: as of late 2018, DynamoDB has native, point in time, backup and restore capabilities, as well as support for Global Tables (cross-region replicated tables)*
2. The article mentions the Export/Import functionality but that is provided by another service: AWS Data Pipleine - which is available though a separate service console - whichbis why you're not finding the Export and Import buttons on the DynamoDB service console

*Unfortunately you can't convert a normal table to a Global table as of mid 2019 so if you're stuck with an already existing table that you need to replicate, you still have to use an offline solution, for now. Hopefully in the near future DynamoDB will add the ability to add/remove replication regions to a DynamoDB table.

The other thing to note is that while the data pipeline solution does work, there are other ways to copy from one table to another which may be worth exploring depending on your situation. For small tables you might just script a simple scan of the source table and put the items in the destination. Etc.